# Which number replaces the question mark?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, puzzle-identification

I'm trying to solve puzzles to exercise my brain. I'm stuck on this test, I printed it from Mensa IQ Test, an app on Android store. Can someone help me?

Below is the test:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, [proper attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at minimum) where it came from. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally [deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism).

Comment: Ok, I will edit it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> 2

> Going clockwise, for each section, sum of the top 2 number is equal to the bottom number of the next section.

> e.g. 6 + 1 (the top 2 numbers) = 7 (the bottom number of the next section). In the next section, 2 + 3 = 5, etc.

Comment: Sniped me by 10 seconds :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be

> **2**

As

> The central number is the sum of the 2 outer numbers in the segment before (going clockwise)

Therefore

> 7+? = 9, so the ? = 2